# Treeview in angular 2 - Alternative for ng-include and passing entire object between components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, tree, angular2-routing

I am trying to create a treeview in angular 2. It is a tree of textboxes with add and delete buttons. I got it running in Angular 1 but it seems way complicated in angular 2.

Angular 1 HTML code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
     <input type="text" ng-model="data.answer" placeholder="Answer" required/>
    <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
    <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>

    </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
        data.nodes.push({answer:'',nodes: []});
    };
    $scope.tree = [{answer:'', nodes: []}];
}]);
```

Ng-include is not there in angular 2. So I tried to use @Input to pass data between the components. But new instance of the object gets created every time which overwrites the previous data!

Is there any way of tackling this in Angular 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `tree` is a nested structure, in Angular2+ we can use component's tag in its template to achieve recursion:

```
export interface Tree {
    nodes: Tree;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'tree-view',
    template: `<ul><li *ngFor="let node of tree.nodes">
               <tree-view [tree]="node"></tree-view></li></ul>`
})
export class TreeViewComponent {
    @Input() public tree: Tree;
}
```

With your specific structure it will go this way:

```
export class TreeData {
    answer: string;
    child: TreeData[];

    constructor(answer: string, child: TreeData[]) {
        this.answer = answer;
        this.child = child;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'tree-view',
    template: `<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let eachChild of tree; let i = index">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newAnswers[i]" placeholder="Answer" required>
        <button (click)="add(newAnswers[i], eachChild)">Add node</button>
        <tree-view [tree]="eachChild.child"></tree-view>
    </li></ul>`
})
export class TreeViewComponent {
    @Input() public tree: TreeData[];
    public newAnswers = Array<string> = [];

    public add(answer: string, node: TreeData) {
        node.child.push({answer, child: []});
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this in my template:                                                                            <li *ngFor="let eachChild of data ; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputData"  placeholder="Answer" required/>
    <button (click)="add(inputData,i)">Add node</button>
    <tree-view [data]="eachChild.child"></tree-view>
</li> .                                                                                                                           And my add function in .ts is :  this.data[index].child.push({answer: inputData, child: []}); My structure is nt retained

Comment: I have created a class in the common file for the structure: 
export class TreeData {
  answer: string;
  child: TreeData[];
  constructor(answer: string, child: TreeData[]) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.child = child;
  }
}

Comment: Should `inputData` be the `answer` from `TreeData`? Or is it an additional component's input?

Comment: Yes. Both represent the input string entered by the user.

Comment: Yes. But how would eachChild.answer be any different from inputData? How would your add function look like? In my code, the complete tree structure is not getting retained. So when I click on "add node" button only the current object gets displayed because previous contents are lost.

Comment: Also added to the answer - I used new property for ngModel and passed whole node instead of index (that was duplicated in each iteration).

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. Just one more thing - All the sibling nodes have the same ngModel i.e. the same data gets displayed in the parallel nodes. How to deal with this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have where to test this code - you could include a plunker next time ;) I've changed the new answers to be an array of strings, that should solve the problem. Also please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Another question! Would be great if you could answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023528/obtaining-treeview-data-in-the-backend-using-dataservice-in-angular-2